# error in binary search program in python

Tags: python, binary-search

hi I m wrtng a very simple Python Program to implement Binary Search.

```
tup=input("enter tup:")
start=0
length=len[tup]
end=tup[length-1]
mid=(int(start)+int(end))/2
key=input("enter value to search")
def search(start,end,key):
  if key==tup[mid]
    print mid
  else if key<tup[mid]
    search(start,mid,key)
  else if key>tup[mid]
    search(mid,end,key)
  else
    return(-1)
```

I get an error as

```
File "binsearch.py", line 8
if key==tup[mid]
               ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I believe I m missing something trivial but unable to figure out.! Let me know if u feel there are any other errors. thanks :)

Comment: The function search seems to do different things in the separate branches. If found, it prints the index acting as a "void function" in C parlance whereas in the last else case something is returned acting like an "int function". A clean  solution would be to return mid in the if branch (shifting the print to the caller) but then returns would also have to be added to the recursive calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You need to end all statements that begin a new block with `:` (i.e. the statements where you increase the indentation level in the next line)
- You need to replace `else if X` with `elif X:`
- You should use `raw_input` instead of `input` as the latter `eval`s whatever the user entered.
- `return` is a statement, not a function, so you do not need `()` around the return value.

Comment: `input` is the correct function for Python 3, `raw_input` for Python 2.

Answer (score 5):

```
 if key==tup[mid]
                 ^
```

needs a `:` at the end

```
                 |
                 v
 if key==tup[mid]:
```

Same problem in the rest of the statement:

```
  else if key<tup[mid]
                      ^
    search(start,mid,key)
  else if key>tup[mid]
                      ^
```

*Aside*:

Instead of `else if` consider using Python's neat `elif` construct, e.g.,

```
  elif key<tup[mid]:
```

etc.